# How to set up ZAP plugin in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, zap

I have a problem on Zap plugin of Jenkins. Assume I have my selenium UI testing code, it will launch a browser and set a proxy automatically. What I need is to launch the test from Jenkins, and use the zap plugin to open the zap proxy and generate report.

The process in Jenkins should be :
1. Open ZAP proxy, add alert filter to ZAP.
2. Execute UI test (which will go through the ZAP proxy automatically)
3. ZAP generate report and send back to Jenkins.
4. Shut down ZAP proxy.

My confusion is when I use the zap plugin in Jenkins, there is a **starting point** which is necessary to put. But I don't want an active scanning, I only need a passive scanning from what go through the zap proxy by UI test. Is there a way to walk around it?

I found another way by using ZAP API to do the job https://medium.com/@PrakhashS/security-testing-for-apis-using-zap-5df8ec07a131. But I don't manage to make a alert filter by API. Can someone help?

I am newbie of Jenkins, I would like to know which way is proposed to meet my need. By executing zap from zap plugin, or by executing shell from zap API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want passive scanning then why not try the ZAP Baseline scan: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ZAP-Baseline-Scan

Theres now an option to add a delay for other tests to proxy through ZAP. I need to update the wiki ;)

Comment: Hi Simon thank you for your reply. But if I use the zap plugin, how can I apply the zap baseline scan from jenkins? I try to configure the zap plugin in jenkins according to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Execute+ZAP+as+part+of+a+Selenium+Build. What I want is to make zap running as a proxy while my testing is going through it, then zap stop and generate report. Is it possible to configure though zap jenkins plugin? Or I need to use command line as you proposed the zap baseline scan?

Comment: They are 2 separate things, you either use one or the other. You can use both if you want, but you'll have to set them up independently.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar - I had an existing UI automation tests, and I was able to proxy them through Zap. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/Soluto/webdriverio-zap-proxy), using webdriver.io (which is basically selenium). If this is what you're looking for, I can help you set this up.

Comment: Hello thank you for your respond, from your example I guess you are using command line to open/test/shutdown zap. However I have specific case linked with Jenkins, or have you also configured from Jenkins?

Comment: No, I am not using Jenkins - I used [zap-cli](https://github.com/Grunny/zap-cli) to control Zap. It was pretty easy, so you might want to consider it.

Comment: I have to use Jenkins since my company runs all the tests there. But it is nice to know about zap-cli, I may reach to you for help if I will use zap-cli :p Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Just to be clear - I am pretty sure you can use zap-cli also from Jenkins...